Lock Sheets with password for another workbook using VBA
I have made a VBA code to extract data from another worksheet and paste on my current workbook/sheet where the Macro Button was implemented. I am trying to insert a line of code to lock the spreadsheet with password for the spreadsheet I'm extracting the data but cant seem to do so with ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOS" . Why is that so?
Option Explicit

    Sub Pull_Data_January()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim objExcel2 As Object, arr As Variant
        Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
        ' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
        With objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Personal File\Personal Files & Forms\File.xlsx")
             
            ' copy the source range to variant array
            arr = .Worksheets("January").Range("E5:AJ43").Value
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOS"
            ' close the source workbook
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        ' select current workbook and paste the values
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("January").Range("E5:AJ43").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
        ' close the source application instance
        objExcel2.Quit
        Set objExcel2 = Nothing


Seems like you pasted some code twice?

.Worksheets("January").Protect Password:="SOS" should do it unless it's some other sheet you're trying to protect.   Using just ActiveSheet with no workbook qualifier will refer to the ActiveSheet in the instance of Excel where your code is running, not to the instance where you opened the file to copy from.  FYI there's no need to create a new instance of Excel just to open another file.

Hi , I replaced ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOS" with your code provided .Worksheets("January").Protect Password:="SOS" , Yet it still does not Protect the sheet that I am trying to protect by the file path.

Please explain exactly which sheet is to be protected.  It’s not really clear in your post.   I guess it’s not in the opened workbook, since you don’t save it

Hi , I want to protect the sheet named "January" from this file path With objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Personal File\Personal Files & Forms\File.xlsx")

Then maybe you should save that file when closing it?

The file is set to autosave. But the macro is still not working to protect it.

Have you tried explicitly saving the file though?

In testing, using .Close savechanges:=True works fine for me: the sheet is protected.

There are the following possibilities

you are protecting the wrong worksheet
you try to protect the right worksheet, but the command is not working.
you are protecting the right worksheet, but the change is not saved.
you are protecting the right worksheet and the change is saved, but there is code in your workbook Workbook_Open() that unprotects the sheet.

In your code, your protecting statement is wrong for 2 reasons. It will protect the current active sheet (that is the sheet that has currently the focus). But you are creating a new instance of Excel (that means Excel runs a 2nd time on your computer) and open your workbook there - this instance will also have an active workbook, but your code will work on the active sheet of the first instance. So theoretically, you could use objExcel2.ActiveSheet.
But even then, it's likely not the correct worksheet. You want to protect the January sheet, but the active sheet of that workbook is the sheet that was active the last time the file was saved - which could be any sheet.
I would suggest to change your code so that you are not using a second instance of Excel - there is simply no need for it and it will slow down your computer. Furthermore, if the macro stops for any reason (any runtime error), you will have a "dead", invisible Excel instance running that you can kill only with the task manager.
Also, you should always specify on which workbook and worksheet you want to work. Your code could look like this:
Sub Pull_Data_January()
    ' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Personal File\Personal Files & Forms\File.xlsx")
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = .Worksheets("January")
        ' copy the source range to variant array
        arr = ws.Range("E5:AJ43").Value
        Debug.Print "Before - Is " & ws.Name & " protected? " & ws.ProtectContents
        ws.Protect Password:="SOS"
        Debug.Print "After  - is " & ws.Name & " protected? " & ws.ProtectContents
        .Close savechanges:=True
    End With
    ' select current workbook and paste the values
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("January").Range("E5").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub

You can see that I added 2 Debug.Print statements that will show you if the sheet was successfully protected - I don't expect that protecting the sheet fails, but this shows the truth. Just have a look to the immediate window, you should see something like this:
Before - Is January protected? False
After  - is January protected? True

You can see that I also changed the Close-statement to .Close savechanges:=True. If the workbook is really set to autosave, this doesn't do any harm, but if not, it is clear why your sheet is never protected.
To exclude the possibility that there is a kind of "auto"-unlocking in the workbook, simply check the workbook code in it. Note that you can prevent that any code is executed automatically by setting Application.EnableEvents = False before you open the workbook - but don't forget to set it back to Application.EnableEvents = True afterwards.

If I were you, I would change the code so that you can pass the month (=sheet) name as parameter. With that, you can reuse the same routine for all of your monthes:
Sub Pull_Data(monthName As String)
    (...)
        Set ws = .Worksheets(monthName)
    (...)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(monthName).Range("E5").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub

Note that you need to put that code into a regular module so that you can call it from anywhere.
The event routine of your button then looks simply like this
Sub JanuaryButton_Click()  
    Pull_Data "January"
End Sub


I tried a macro button with the above code , but it seems like after going back to the excel file path the fields of "E5:AJ43" is still not protected with password. Upon clicking on the macro there is nothing that poped out.

There is nothing popping out, it's written to the immediate window (press Ctrl+G in the VBA editor). If you mention that only the range "E5:AJ43": Is that range marked as "Locked" (Format->Protection)?
